# Changing JSON Structure in Chrome Extension Update?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, jstree

I'm building a Chrome extension that will save a JSON string to the user's local storage.

At the moment, I'm building an MVP, but in the future, I'd like people to be able to upgrade to a premium account.

The premium version that I'm envisioning will need more levels in the JSON string than the MVP will. Basically, more granular data.

For the MVP, should I build the simpler or more complicated JSON string? If I build the simple one now, will it be hard to transfer user's data to a more complicated data structure in an update?

In case it matters, I'll be using the JSON string to create jstrees. (...I think.)

Comment: chrome.storage API saves objects so no need to stringify JSON. As for extensibility, it depends. I think the question is not answerable without some examples of the structure.